# get the most recent updated record for each ID in the given list of IDs. LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have  a Table, in SQLserver, called **CandidateContacts**  which has the following fields **Id, createDate,dateUpdated,address**.

I am trying to get the most recent updated record for each ID for the given list of IDs.

```
List<int?> candidateIds = new List<int?>;

candidateIds .Add(761);
candidateIds .Add(789);
candidateIds .Add(742);
```

The following statement gives the following error :

> Operator '&&' cannot be applied on operands of type 'bool and 'DateTime?'

```
var itemsMax = db.CandidateContacts.Where(x => candidateIds.Contains(x.idCandidateLogin) && db.CandidateContacts.Max(y => y.dateUpdated));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `GroupBy` and get the first element of each group after your order by `dateUpdated` in descending order:

```
var res = await db.CandidateContacts.Where(p => candidateIds.Contains(p.idCandidateLogin))
                                    .GroupBy(y => y.idCandidateLogin)
                                    .Select(g=>g.OrderByDescending(y => y.dateUpdated).FirstOrDefault()).ToListAsync();
```